# svn merge: source under renamed folder not merged

Tags: file, svn, merge, tree-conflict

```
trunk ---------------------------renamed dir a/b to a/g ---------------------
           \                                                                /
            \                                                              /
           branches/1.0----------------------modified file a/b/Hello.java --
```

Merge the branch to trunk.

```
 svn  merge ^/myproject/branches/1.0
```

Get conflict

```
   Tree conflict on 'a\b'
   > local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
    Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help: r
```

if I select "mark resolved", the modified file Hello.java under a/b is ignored(not merged). What should I do to pull the changed files under conflict tree (e.g. Hello.java)? How to merge in this senario?

svn, version 1.9.1 (r1698128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merge on the folder level directly in this case

```
cd trunk_working_copy
svn  merge ^/myproject/branches/1.0/a/b ./a/g
```